# cmd launch windows software center to install updates remotely

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, updates

I have a network that uses SCCM and the sccm admin is never around. I need a way to batch launch windows software center (sccm client) and install all available updates. The machines are on at different times and I get a schedualed maint window that moves based on user work load. I currently have to log onto every station and launch the GUI. need a batch cmd solution. Powershell has not worked and third party software is out of the question. Any ideas how to remotely launch software center and install available software remotely with the command propt? WMI? please help.